# Hide/Show MdiChilds

Tags: c#, show, mdichild

I have an application with mdi. I have on the parent some links which, when clicked open a new  child form and hides the one that is already opened
How can I check if a child is already opened?

```
A little scenario:  
link 1 -> opens Child of type A  
link 2 -> opens Child of type B  
link 3 -> open Child of type C  

Application start:  
click on link 1-> check if a child of type A is opened 

 - yes -> hides the current opened child and shows the A-type Child
 - no: -> hides the current opened child and creates a new A-type child and shows it  

click on link 2 -> check if a child of type B is opened  

 - yes -> hides the current opened child and shows the B-type Child  
 - no: -> hides the current opened child and creates a new A-type child and shows it

etc..
```

can you help please with some code?
Thank you...

**UPDATE:**
something like this?

```
 foreach (Form aForm in this.MdiChildren)
            {
                aForm.Hide();
            }
        foreach (Form f in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (f.Name == "VizualizareArticol")
                f.Show();
            else
            {
                VizualizareArticol vv = new VizualizareArticol();
                vv.MdiParent = this;
                vv.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                vv.Location = new Point(0, 0);

                vv.Show();
            }
        }
```

but doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Check for Control.Visible. If Item is visible you can .Hide it, if its not Visible . Otherwise look at the objects you create.

If you already created a form and have hidden it, it becomes invisible. Therefore you can check for .Visible and display the form.

```
if(null != aForm  && !aForm.Visible){
    aForm.Show() 
    aForm.BringToFront();
}else if(null == aForm){
    // create the form
}
// otherwise form is existing & visible
```

Comment: didn't understand the idea you have said

Comment: if you hide a form with aForm.Hide it is invisible. Therfore if(aForm != null) you can check for if(!aForm.Visible)